# ASP.NET Core 1.0 SynchronizationContext

Tags: asp.net-core

Is SynchronizationContext null in an ASP.NET Core 1.0 website?
This code throws an exception on my system:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var sc = System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current;
            if (sc == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("SynchronizationContext is null");
            }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SynchronizationContext.Current is null when run on different app domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521286/synchronizationcontext-current-is-null-when-run-on-different-app-domains)

Comment: It is not a duplicate!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is gone in ASP.NET 5 as you don't need its functionality. Its whole purpose was to flow HttpContext.Current which is gone.

> I think it was also doing something with the current culture but I am not sure how that is handled now.

Comment: To make the current culture "async-friendly", there are actually 2 strategies: on CoreCLR and .NET 4.6, a special `Switch.System.Globalization.NoAsyncCurrentCulture` flag is used: it was previously set to false by dnx's `Bootstrapper` but it's now directly handled in mscorlib: https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/AppContext/AppContextDefaultValues.Defaults.cs. On .NET <4.5.2, a special `HostExecutionContextManager` is used instead: https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/blob/dev/src/dnx.clr.managed/DnxHostExecutionContextManager.cs

Comment: That would be really cool to flow the culture through an accessor, too (just like HttpContext).

Comment: I was under the faulty assumption ASP.NET 5 has a single-thread execution similar to node. So, this means contexts can be handled by separate threads and an await may bring you to another thread?

Comment: @MasterT not sure if I understood. What I was getting at here is the fact that there is no `HttpContext.Current` in the new world which is static. So, sharing that between threads was the hard work (AFAIK, here is [the implementation of `SynchronizationContext` in System.Web](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/AspNetSynchronizationContext.cs))

Comment: @MasterT true, any `await` call made on a `Task` which is not already completed will likely cause a thread switch.